# Imprimir los indexOf de Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer una especie de filtro de un array en JavaScript por medio de un checkbox html, cuando está checkeado busca los index que empiezan con "Motorola", el tema es así, los encuentra pero me los muestra como -1 o 0, estoy trabado, no sé cómo escribir la condición de que si el indexOf da 0, entonces sólo imprime esos que tienen ese index.

El código que les estoy pasando imprime en el html sólo los 0 y -1. Igual la condición también me dificulta, ¿qué pongo?

```js
if(listadoCelulares[i].indexOf("Motorola")==0){
    //Algo así?? ando chueco en javascript
}
```

```js
function refinarMarca(){

listadoCelulares = [
    {

        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {
        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Samsung",
        "modelo": "GALAXY J5 J510",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5.2,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "720x1280",
        "camara_resolucion": "13 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Samsung",
        "modelo": "GALAXY J7 J710",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5.5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "13 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Huawei",
        "modelo": "Y360D",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 4,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "800x480",
        "camara_resolucion": "5 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "2 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "4 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Lenovo",
        "modelo": "VIBE K5",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "800x480",
        "camara_resolucion": "13 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    }
];



function refinarMarca(){

var motorolaCheckbox= document.getElementById("motorola");

        if(motorolaCheckbox.checked){



            for(var i=0; i<listadoCelulares.length; i++){


            var ulElegido= document.getElementById("ListadoTotal"); 
                var liMarca= document.createElement("li");
                    ulElegido.appendChild(liMarca); 
                        var displayMarca= document.createTextNode(listadoCelulares[i].marca.indexOf("Motorola"));


                            liMarca.appendChild(displayMarca);


        }

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supongo que tu for debería ser algo así :

```
        var ulElegido= document.getElementById("ListadoTotal"); 

        for(var i=0; i<listadoCelulares.length; i++){    

          if(listadoCelulares[i].marca.indexOf("Motorola")==0){ 
          // solo si encuentra agrega
           var liMarca= document.createElement("li");
           ulElegido.appendChild(liMarca); 
           var displayMarca = document.createTextNode(listadoCelulares[i].marca);
           //agrega la marca o lo que quieras
           liMarca.appendChild(displayMarca);

        }
     }
```

Por cierto, el indexOf lo que hace es devolverte el indice donde encuentra el elemento, por eso como siempre estas poniendo la marca como primer ítem(posición 0) si encuentra devolverá 0, y cuando no encuentra devuelve -1.

Comment: Me anduvo perfecto realmente, creo que ya lo tenia muy parecido en mi cabeza pero tenia que reorganizarme un poco las ideas y esta fue la solución gracias, también funciona con != -1 como uno respondió arriba.

Comment: Si, trate de adaptarlo a tu código inicial, pero mejor seria el != -1, por si el elemento se encuentra en otro indice diferente al primero(0), a menos que sea una regla que se encuentre en el primer elemento. Gracias y suerte

Answer (score 4):

En realidad, el metodo `IndexOf()` devuelve la posición de la primera ocurrencia de un valor especificado en una cadena, pero si no encuentra ninguna coincidencia entonces devuelve **-1**, lo que quiere decir que no siempre va a devolver 0, por ejemplo

```js
var str = "Hola mundo, bienvenido al universo.";
var indexOfValue = str.indexOf("universo");
```

- En el ejemplo anterior el valor de indexOfValue es 26.

Por lo tanto lo que necesitas hacer en tu for es evaluar si el resultado es diferente de -1, de la siguiente forma:

```js
if(listadoCelulares[i].marca.indexOf("Motorola") != -1){
     var displayMarca= document.createTextNode(listadoCelulares[i].marca);
     liMarca.appendChild(displayMarca);
 }
```

Te dejo un ejemplo aquí (también en [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htd5Lja1/)):

```js
listadoCelulares = [
    {

        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {
        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Samsung",
        "modelo": "GALAXY J5 J510",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5.2,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "720x1280",
        "camara_resolucion": "13 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Samsung",
        "modelo": "GALAXY J7 J710",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5.5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "13 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Huawei",
        "modelo": "Y360D",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 4,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "800x480",
        "camara_resolucion": "5 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "2 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "4 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Lenovo",
        "modelo": "VIBE K5",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "800x480",
        "camara_resolucion": "13 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    }
];

$('input[name=checkgroup]').change(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        refinarMarca();
    }
    else
    {
        // Checkbox is not checked.
    }    

});

function refinarMarca(){

var motorolaCheckbox= document.getElementById("motorola");
if(motorolaCheckbox.checked){
 for(var i=0; i<listadoCelulares.length; i++){
  var ulElegido= document.getElementById("ListadoTotal"); 
    var liMarca= document.createElement("li");
  if(listadoCelulares[i].marca.indexOf("Motorola") != -1){
   var stringData = listadoCelulares[i].marca
                        + " " + listadoCelulares[i].modelo
                        + " " + listadoCelulares[i].sistema_operativo
                        + " " + listadoCelulares[i].pantalla_pulgadas
                        + " " + listadoCelulares[i].pantalla_resolucion
                        + " " + listadoCelulares[i].camara_resolucion
                        + " " + listadoCelulares[i].camara_frontal
                        + " " + listadoCelulares[i].camara_frontal_res
                        + " " + listadoCelulares[i].memoria_interna
                        + " " + listadoCelulares[i].flash;
                        
                        
     var displayMarca= document.createTextNode(stringData);
     liMarca.appendChild(displayMarca);
          ulElegido.appendChild(liMarca); 
     }
     }
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<body>
<input name="checkgroup" type="checkbox" id="motorola"> Motorola
<ul id="ListadoTotal">
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Este no lo usé pero es muy parecido al que usé realmente de gran ayuda y el != anda muy bien...

Answer (score 0):

adicionalmente podrías filtrar tu array mediante una función enviada como parámetro al método [filter(function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

```js
listadoCelulares = [
    {

        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {
        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    },
    {

        "marca": "Samsung",
        "modelo": "GALAXY J5 J510",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5.2,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "720x1280",
        "camara_resolucion": "13 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB",
        "flash": "si"
    }
    
];

function filtromarca(obj) {
    let valor = document.getElementById('marca').value;
  return ('marca' in obj && obj.marca!= null && obj.marca==valor) 
}

function filtro(){
 let arr =listadoCelulares.filter(filtromarca); //Filtro
 var ulElegido= document.getElementById("ListadoTotal"); 
 ulElegido.innerHTML = ""; //Limpiar la Lista
 Object.keys(arr).forEach(function(key, index) {
       var liMarca= document.createElement("li");
           ulElegido.appendChild(liMarca); 
           var displayMarca = document.createTextNode(this[key].marca);//puede Acceder a cualquier clave de su array (marca ,so, etc)
           liMarca.appendChild(displayMarca);
 }, arr);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="marca" name="marca" value="Motorola" onclick="return filtro(this);">Motorola
<ul id="ListadoTotal">
  
</ul>
```